# An error is displayed regarding rigify

Tags: rigify

[image]

I made a model using rigify.
I pressed generate to create a copy and gave it auto weight.
However, there was a mistake, so I deleted the copy again.
I repeated this several times and opened the blender again, and this error came up when I opened this file.

***For security reasons, automatic execution of Python scripts in this file was disabled:
Text 'rig_ui.py'***

What should I do to avoid this error? I looked it up, but there was no answer, so I have a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "warning" is no error, it is just a general warning. You could in python generally do "anything": delete file on your computer, change them, harm them. So if you enable automatic execution, this could damage your computer. That's why the warning is coming.
But of course, if you press "Ignore" rigify won't work because the script won't be allowed to run.

Comment: If the computer is broken, there is no reason to use rigify. Thank you.